# detect and sum NA's by group with aggregate

Tags: r, aggregate

I was hoping to detect and sum missing observations by group.  I attempted to use `aggregate`, but could not get it to work.  Below is an example data set and the desired result.

```
my.data = read.table(text = "
    GROUP     Z
        1    NA
        1    NA
        1    NA
        2     A
        2    NA
        2    NA
        2     A
        3     A
        3     A
        3    NA
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "NA")
my.data

desired.result <- read.table(text = "
   GROUP    Z my.na my.sum
       1 <NA>  TRUE      3
       1 <NA>  TRUE      3
       1 <NA>  TRUE      3
       2    A  TRUE      2
       2 <NA>  TRUE      2
       2 <NA>  TRUE      2
       2    A  TRUE      2
       3    A  TRUE      1
       3    A  TRUE      1
       3 <NA>  TRUE      1
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "NA")
```

Here is the code I used:

```
my.na  <- aggregate(my.data$Z ~ my.data$GROUP, FUN = function(x) any(is.na(x)))
colnames(my.na) <- c('GROUP', 'my.na')

my.sum <- aggregate(my.data$Z ~ my.data$GROUP, FUN = function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
colnames(my.sum) <- c('GROUP', 'my.sum')

my.data2 <- merge(my.data , my.na , by=c('GROUP'), all=TRUE)
my.data2 <- merge(my.data2, my.sum, by=c('GROUP'), all=TRUE)
my.data2
```

The functions above work outside of `aggregate`, as shown below:

```
x <- c(NA, 1, 3, NA, NA)
sum(is.na(x))
# [1] 3

any(is.na(x))
# [1] TRUE
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: See the "na.action" argument of `aggreagte.formula`; `aggregate(Z ~ GROUP, my.data, function(x) sum(is.na(x)), na.action = NULL)`.

Comment: @alexis_laz Thank you.  If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Just as I was ready to press the submit button I thought to try:

```
with(my.data, aggregate(Z, by = list(GROUP), FUN = function(x) any(is.na(x)) ))

with(my.data, aggregate(Z, by = list(GROUP), FUN = function(x) sum(is.na(x)) ))
```

This works.  Although, I do not know why the `list` approach works and the `~` approach does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
require(data.table)
my.data = data.table(my.data)
my.data[,list(Z,my.na = any(is.na(Z)), my.sum = sum(is.na(Z))),by="GROUP"]
```

[image]

Comment: When showing text output, it's always better to show the output in text form rather than via an image. This helps it display correctly on any size browser.

Comment: You should also add some explanation about your solution and why it works.